# Add a row in sequential number

Tags: excel, vba

I am adding a row at the bottom of the table using -

```
Dim Lr As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Lr = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Searching last row in column B
    Rows(Lr + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'Inserting new row
    Cells(Lr + 1, "B") = Cells(Lr, "B") + 1 'Adding a sequential number
    Rows(Lr).Copy 'Copying format of last row
    Rows(Lr + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats 'Pasting format to new row
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Deactivating copy mode
```

There are some formulas in the row which want to be copied in the new row.  With

```
Rows(Lr + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:xlPasteFormats
```

it paste a new row only with sequential number but not formulas.  And with

```
Rows(Lr + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:xlPasteFormulas
```

it paste a new row only with formulas but without sequential number.  Somewhere something is missing. 
Please help me.

Comment: so you're saying that this `Cells(Lr + 1, "B") = Cells(Lr, "B") + 1` is not working? does it leave the new cell empty or not increment it or what?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will achieve what you expect, I've made a few adjustments to your code, also it's always a good idea to declare the Sheet you are working with, so Excel doesn't assume that it is ActiveSheet, also I've changed the Integer to Long as Excel has more rows than an Integer can handle, please have a look below:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with, amend ActiveSheet to "Sheets("YourSheetName")"
Dim Lr As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Lr = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Searching last row in column B
    ws.Rows(Lr + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'Inserting new row
    ws.Rows(Lr).Copy 'Copying format of last row
    ws.Rows(Lr + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats 'Pasting format to new row
    ws.Rows(Lr + 1).PasteSpecial Paste: xlPasteFormulas
    ws.Cells(Lr + 1, "B") = ws.Cells(Lr, "B") + 1 'Adding a sequential number
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'Deactivating copy mode
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```